# Tic Tac Toe Java Invalid user input when entering letters rather than numbers

Tags: java, input, tic-tac-toe

When a user inputs a letter rather than a number an InputMistmatchException error occurs and the program exits.

How can I change it so that the program will print "Invalid input, please enter a number" instead of just exiting? Is there another way other than using catch? I found that online but I don't think my teacher will allow it.

This is my Main class if it helps

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
    game.printBoard();
    System.out.println(game.getDirections());
    
    // Keep playing the game until it is over
    while (!game.checkWin()) {
      // Read the next move from the user
      int move = scanner.nextInt();
      
      // Make the move and update the game state
      boolean spaceNotOccupied = game.checkInput(move);
            if (spaceNotOccupied) {
                game.makeMove(move);
            }
      
      // Check if the game is over
      if (game.checkWin()) {
        game.printResults();
        return;
      }
      
      // Change the current player and print the updated game board
      game.changePlayer();
      game.printBoard();
      System.out.println(game.getDirections());
    }
    
    // Print the final result of the game
    game.printResults();
    
    }
  }
```

And this is the makeMove method where it shows the numbers to enter

```
  
  public void makeMove(int space) {
  // Update the game board
    if (space == 1) {
    s1 = turn;
  } else if (space == 2) {
    s2 = turn;
  } else if (space == 3) {
    s3 = turn;
  } else if (space == 4) {
    s4 = turn;
  } else if (space == 5) {
    s5 = turn;
  } else if (space == 6) {
    s6 = turn;
  } else if (space == 7) {
    s7 = turn;
  } else if (space == 8) {
    s8 = turn;
  } else if (space == 9) {
    s9 = turn;
  } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again.");
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could wrap `int move = scanner.nextInt();` in a `try` and `catch` block that catches `InputMistmatchException` and prints your desired error message.

Comment: `int move = scanner.nextInt();` will cause your issue - while you could trap the exception you also need to clear the buffer (ie `nextLine`) - or, you could use `nextLine` directly and then parse the `String`, making sure you trap the possible `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly assuming (using) the input as `Integer`, first verify if it is `Integer` or not. If not, loop till you get one.

```
// Read the next move from the user    
System.out.print("Please provide your next move");
while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
     System.out.print("Invalid input, please enter a number");
     scan.next();
}
     
int move = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with String input instead of assuming the input represents an integer, and then check whether that string consists of a digit, ...etc.

Not your question, but your code would still change the player when the user inputs a square that is already occupied. You should only change the player when the move was actually made.

Here is suggested code (which I did not test, as I don't have the rest of your code):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
        
        // Keep playing the game until it is over
        while (true) {
            game.printBoard();
            System.out.println(game.getDirections());
            
            // Read the next move from the user as a string
            String moveString = scanner.nextLine();
            if (moveString.matches("[1-9]")) { // Is it a single digit between 1 and 9?
                int move = Integer.valueOf(moveString); // Convert to integer
                if (game.checkInput(move)) { // Is the square free?
                    game.makeMove(move);
                    if (game.checkWin()) break;
                    game.changePlayer();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("That square is already occupied.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a digit between 1 and 9.");
            }
        }
        game.printResults();
        scanner.close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use infinite loop to do that, but you need to check if the user is winning for every valid input.

```
boolean playing = true;
while(playing){
   switch(space){
      case 1:
           //code for doing operation
           //winning check
           break;
      ...
      default:
           System.out.println("Invalid Input");
   }          
}
```